# apparmor command not found on my new debian 10 "buster"

Tags: linux, path, debian-buster, apparmor

I recently switched from ubuntu to Debian 10, when I tried to run

> apparmor

it says command not found even if as sudo.

I then checked my $PATH variable it says "

> bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games: No such file or directory

why it's saying No such file or directory.

I also installed

> apparmor-utils

still, the situation doesn't change.

please help me, this is my first question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

`#systemctl status apparmor` or `#systemctl enable apparmor`. You can use `disable`, `start`, `stop` as well.